# How do I make the Calendar app stop harassing me about permissions?

Tags: notifications, permissions

A few months ago I got a new phone.  After a bit, I tapped on the Calendar app, and it popped up with a supremely silly request: it wanted access to my contact list!

Now there's no good reason why an app should need my contacts in order to show me a calendar, so I denied the permission, figuring it would go on just fine without it.  Apparently not; though!  The app failed to launch, and ever since then, multiple times a day, it's been throwing notifications at me that the Calendar app needs me to go in and enable that permission.

Well, screw that!  There is no conceivable reason why a calendar app could possibly require access to my contacts to run.  To support certain features, perhaps, but *to run at all?*  No.  Just no.  But it keeps spamming me with requests to enable it.

How do I make the notifications stop?  It's a system app that I can't uninstall, but at this point all I want is to shut the thing up!

Comment: What is the device model? Not all Calendar apps behave like that, so without any more information, it's difficult to find the solution. Otherwise... try a 3rd-party Calendar app instead.

Comment: Even if it is a system app you should be able to clear it's app data and may be even disable the whole calendar app. BTW: What is the package name of the calendar app? On my system the calendar app is not a system app.

Comment: OEMs suck, most of the times. That's why there's rooting and custom ROMs.